# How to copy files from jupyter lab to Google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub, jupyter-irkernel

I'm trying to copy jupyter lab files to Google drive location, But I'm not able to copy files to google drive location by using copy options.

So How I can copy these files. Can you suggest any solutions to solve this problem?

Comment: Are the tags (google-drive-sdk jupyter-notebook jupyter-lab jupyterhub jupyter-irkernel) you listed relevant? If not, you are spamming SO environment.

Comment: @swatchai I have listed tags are correct only because using google cloud SDK we are connecting to google drive and we are using all jupyter extensions

Comment: I think you need to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: You can check this extension from github - [jupyterlab-google-drive](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-google-drive). This extension adds a Google Drive filebrowser to the left sidepanel of JupyterLab. When you are logged into your Google account, you will have the files stored in it available to JupyterLab.